# How to make sublime wrap-line support half-width and full-width characters?

Tags: sublimetext3, word-wrap, key-bindings

I make use of Sublime Emacs Pro Essentials Package.
If you press Alt-Q, wrap-line will be executed which is a function to fold lines around the cursor at a given length,
but it does not distinguish between half-width and full-width characters (=double-width ones such as Japanese Kanji) in the count.

For this reason, the apparent width varies between lines composed of full-width characters and lines composed of half-width characters.
Is there a wrap-line function that counts full-width characters as two letters and make the apparent width of all lines the same regardless of the composition of letters.

Comment: I'm not sure about that particular package, but the source for the `wrap_lines` command in core Sublime that does this is available in `Default/paragraph.py` so it's possible to see what it's doing and then implement a "smarter" version, in theory.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the name of the module to be fixed. It is likely to be possible to align display widths of half-width and full-width characters lines by fixing it. And it seems not to be too difficult. I'll try it!